# Rules of natural deduction

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

In class my professor introduced rules involving

Introduction of $\lor$: $\begin{array}{c}
\varphi\\
\hline\hline
\varphi \lor \psi
\end{array}$

Elimination of $\lor$: $\begin{array}{c}
\varphi \lor \psi \quad \varphi\rightarrow a \quad \psi \rightarrow a\\
\hline\hline
a
\end{array}$

I just wonder can I simply put $\neg$ in? Like rewriting in "negate version"

$\begin{array}{c}
\neg \varphi\\
\hline\hline
\neg (\varphi \lor \psi)
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{c}
\neg (\varphi \lor \psi) \quad \varphi\rightarrow \neg a \quad \psi \rightarrow \neg a\\
\hline\hline
a
\end{array}$

They seem to be right, but I can't find the proof trees.

---

Edit: introduction and elimination of $\neg$ were introduced in class:

Introduction: $\begin{array}{c}
\varphi\rightarrow \psi \quad \varphi \rightarrow \neg \psi\\
\hline\hline
\neg \varphi
\end{array}$

Elimination: $\begin{array}{c}
\neg \neg \varphi\\
\hline\hline
\varphi
\end{array}$

Might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cant introduce negation directly like that.

However

$\begin{array}{c}
\neg \varphi\\
\hline\hline
(\neg \varphi \lor \psi)
\end{array}$

and there is no coresponding direct rule for the second one. To see that 
$\begin{array}{c}
\neg \varphi\\
\hline\hline
\neg (\varphi \lor \psi)
\end{array}$

is not correct, just notice the case where $\psi$ is $\top$ i.e. the predicate which is allways true. Then $\neg(\varphi\vee \psi)$ is allways false, something which we surely should not be able to conclude from any sentence $\neg \varphi$.

Comment: Oh right, I see the first one with no problem. But is $\begin{array}{c}
\neg \varphi \quad \neg \psi\\
\hline\hline
\neg( \varphi \lor \psi)
\end{array}$ legit? (Seems like another version of $\land$) What about the second one?

Comment: @MonkeyKing that rule follows from introduction of $\land$ and de Morgan's law.